# CakePHP Username URL using Regex?

Tags: regex, cakephp, routes, friendly-url

I found a comment here: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/PHPdiddy/2006/10/06/custom-urls-from-the-site-root

That said:

> Just change last line.
>   Router::connect('/*',
>   array('controller' => 'members',
>   'action' => 'show'));
>
>   to
>
>       Router::connect('(?!admin|items|images)(.**)',
>       array('controller' => 'members', 'action' => 'show'));

Some people were able to get that to work... It didn't look quite right to me though so I tried the following, but still had no luck:

```
Router::connect('(?!/admin|/items|/images)(/.*)',
array('controller' => 'members','action' => 'show'));
```

In any case, the goal is to have a url like http://domainname/username , map to a users unique id. It works with /*, but I rather not use that method. Ideas?

**Update to solution:**
I used the selected answer below and added the following. It may be helpful to someone else.

```
$misc = array(*your misc webroot, admin route items here...*);
$notList = array_merge(Configure::listObjects('plugin'),Configure::listObjects('controller'));
$notListLowerCase = array();
foreach ($notList as $key=>$item):
    $notListLowerCase[] = strtolower(preg_replace("/(.)([A-Z])/","\\1_\\2",$item));
endforeach;
$notList = array_merge($notList,$misc,$notListLowerCase);
$notList = implode('|', $notList);

Router::connect('/:username', 
        array(
            'controller'=>'users', 
            'action'=>'view'
        ),   
        array(
            'username' => '\b(?:(?!'.$notList.')\w)+\b'
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here ya go.  You need to capture it as a param and then reference it in the regex.  The username will be available in $this->params['username'] in the controller action.

```
Router::connect('/:username', 
    array(
        'controller'=>'members', 
        'action'=>'show'
    ),   
    array(
        'username' => '\b(?:(?!admin|items|images)\w)+\b'
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you!! It worked perfectly. I added extra info to the question using your solution so that you don't need to type in all the controller names etc!

Answer (score -1):

```
$misc = array(*your misc webroot, admin route items here...*);
    $notList = array_merge(App::objects('plugin'),str_replace('Controller','',App::objects('controller')));
    $notListLowerCase = array();
    foreach ($notList as $key=>$item):
        $notListLowerCase[] = strtolower(preg_replace("/(.)([A-Z])/","\\1_\\2",$item));
    endforeach;
    $notList = array_merge($notList,$misc,$notListLowerCase);
    $notList = implode('|', $notList);
    Router::connect('/:username', array('controller' => 'members', 'action' => 'show'),array('pass'=>array('username'),'username'=>'\b(?:(?!'.$notList.')\w)+\b'));
```